# Select in MySQL with priority

Tags: mysql

I've table data looks like this:

[image: SQL]

How do in SQL if I want to select data with limit 5 and show by priority type=image as much as 70% and type=text as much as 30%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this query :

```
(SELECT * FROM `tablename` where `type` = 'text' limit 0,2) UNION (SELECT * FROM `tablename` where `type` = 'image' limit 0,5)
```

It return something like this ,

```
+--------+-------+------------+
| id     |  type | value      |
+--------+-------+------------+
|   1    | text  | text1      |
|   2    | text  | text2      |
|   4    | image | image1.jpg |
|   5    | image | image2.jpg |
|   6    | image | image3.jpg |
|   7    | image | image4.jpg |
|   8    | image | image5.jpg |
+--------+--------------------+
```

Comment: This is one option that we can use but other options may available. Follow question soon i will send other.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in one query will require running totals and will be fairly complex.  A nicer solution might be to do two separate queries and then aggregate the results set together using a `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE type='text'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE type='image'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 7
```

I am returning 10 rows because 30% and 70% of 5 does not give a whole number.  I am also eschewing the case where there might be fewer than 3 or 7 records for types of `text` and `image`, respectively, which would throw off your desired ratio.

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` is a serious performance killer. Read http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: Did the OP mention performance as being critical, or did it mention very large tables?

Comment: No. But SO is a public platform and I thought it was necessary to mention, so that help-seekers are aware of that issue.